# Are the model structure(s) on chain complexes and the triangulated structure interchangeable, or complementary?

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, derived-functors, model-categories

I am somewhat new to homotopy theory and homological algebra, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I am wondering if the triangulated structure on the category $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathsf{A})$ of chain complexes in an abelian category $\mathsf{A}$ can be entirely replaced by a choice of [Quillen model structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+chain+complexes) on $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathsf{A})$ and/or its relevant subcategories (bounded complexes above/below, etc.).

For example, suppose I knew only abstract homotopy theory (Quillen model categories etc.) and the model structures on chain complexes of sheaves. Would I be able to compute sheaf cohomology and the usual derived functors using only that data? Or is it still necessary to know the distinguished triangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinguished triangles are uniquely determined
by the model structure, they are precisely the homotopy cofiber sequences.

Furthermore, the triangulated structure is also uniquely determined
by the model structure: the homotopy category of a stable model category
is a triangulated category.

Since any practical example of a triangulated category is induced
by a stable model category (a counterexample is a paper in Inventiones, by the way), there is no real reason to use triangulated categories;
they are a lingering remnant of the time when all the powerful model-categorical tools discovered in the last 20 years were not yet available.

Comment: Awesome! Do you happen to know of a reference that discusses homological algebra from this point of view?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ: The very basic aspects are treated in Chapter 7 of Hovey's Model Categories.  Chapter 1 of Lurie's Higher Algebra treats more advanced aspects, albeit using quasicategories, which are, however, quite similar to model categories for many practical purposes.